# Loading {logistf} breaks MCMCglmm()

Tags: r, logistf

Loading the package `logistf` breaks `MCMCglmm()`. Unloading `logistf` before running the command doesn't remove the error.

Why is that? Is there a way to solve this?

**Works**

```r
library(MCMCglmm)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> Loading required package: coda
#> Loading required package: ape

data(PlodiaPO)
MCMCglmm(PO ~ plate, data = PlodiaPO)
#> 
#>                        MCMC iteration = 0
#> 
#>                        MCMC iteration = 1000
#> 
#>                        MCMC iteration = 2000
#> 
#>                        MCMC iteration = 3000
#> 
[...]
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "MCMCglmm"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Doesn't work**

```r
library(logistf)
library(MCMCglmm)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> Loading required package: coda
#> Loading required package: ape

data(PlodiaPO)
MCMCglmm(PO ~ plate, data = PlodiaPO)
#> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data): invalid term in model formula

unloadNamespace("logistf")
MCMCglmm(PO ~ plate, data = PlodiaPO)
#> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data): invalid term in model formula
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research i found that the problem not from `logistf` but it comes from the imported package `formula.tools` to reproduce the error try :

```
library(formula.tools)
#>formula.tools-1.7.1 - Copyright © 2022 Decision Patterns
library(MCMCglmm)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> Loading required package: coda
#> Loading required package: ape

data(PlodiaPO)
MCMCglmm(PO ~ plate, data = PlodiaPO)

#> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  invalid term in model formula
```

and this issue known for `formula.tools` see  [Weird package dependency introduces error](https://github.com/lrberge/fixest/issues/210)

The solution detailed in this issue is:

- fork fomula.tools repo
- (remove this line)[https://github.com/decisionpatterns/formula.tools/blob/45b6654e4d8570cbaf1e2fd527652471202d97ad/NAMESPACE#L3]
- install_github from your repo

OR

- run `as.character.formula = function(x) as.character.default(x)` right after loading formula.tools. That might break code using as.character.formula though (but not sure).

Thanks for this question

Comment: I would just like to add that we are aware of the problems with `formula.tools`, which is why the dependency will be dropped, see https://github.com/georgheinze/logistf/pull/55. This might be on CRAN with the next update.